# ON DELETE CASCADE doesn't work when columns contains NULL

Tags: t-sql

ON DELETE CASCADE does not work in the code below.

I expect an empty response but the inserted record is still there.

(It is not possible to create a Primary Key in Parent because Column2 allows NULL.)

Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
  Column1 INT NOT NULL,
  Column2 INT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Child (
  Column1 INT NOT NULL,
  Column2 INT NULL,
  AdditionalInfo INT NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE Parent ADD CONSTRAINT UQ UNIQUE CLUSTERED (Column1, Column2) 

ALTER TABLE Child
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Parent_Child] FOREIGN KEY(Column1, Column2) 
REFERENCES Parent(Column1, Column2)
ON DELETE CASCADE

INSERT INTO Parent (Column1, Column2) VALUES(1, NULL)
INSERT INTO Child (Column1, Column2, AdditionalInfo) VALUES(1, NULL, 1)

DELETE FROM Parent WHERE Column1=1 AND Column2 IS NULL

SELECT * FROM Child
```

Comment: Make the column `not null default 0`?

Comment: No, because 0 is not the same as NULL

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with column2 null values. If you want to work DELETE CASCADE properly, you have to set a default value to columns that reference each other.

In your case, two columns have NULL values, which means nothing to the SQL server, so it can't delete the row from the "Child" table. Think, you maybe have millions of data like this, which null rows will SQL SERVER have to delete? How will he know that?

If you update two columns with the same value and then run your delete, you will see your delete cascade works fine, or you can set a default value for that two columns. It will work fine.

So you have to set the default value for your columns that use this.